# Integrable function whose Fourier transform is constant

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Does there exist an integrable function whose continuous Fourier transform equals a constant $c \neq 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$? That is, does there exist a function $f \in L_1$ such that $\hat{f}(x) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(t)e^{-2\pi i xt}dt = c$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, with $c \neq 0$?

I don't think so, but I'm not really sure how I would go about proving/disproving this feeling. I have not yet been introduced to Fourier transforms. A hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Dirac Delta Function?

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, but the delta function has a constant Fourier transform. This has important consequences in physics, such as having a localized position in QM leads to having a completely unknown momentum!

Comment: I'm not very advanced in math and I've heard that that probably counts as a distribution not a function, but anyways it's useful in Physics.

Comment: @QuantumFool "Function"

Comment: @Doug haha you beat me by ~5 seconds. I'm a physics person so that's where I learned about Dirac Deltas and all

Comment: @QuantumFool Not really looking for Dirac Delta no! I know it exists and can be rigorized but in my context this would just be equal to zero.

Comment: @Jori " in my context this would just be equal to zero" ? not really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there exists an integrable function $f$ such that
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_{-\infty} f(x) e^{-2\pi i x \xi}\ dx = 1
\end{align}
then it follows
\begin{align}
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(x)e^{-2\pi i x n} \ dx = 1 
\end{align}
for all $n$ but this contradictions Riemann Lebesgue lemma.

Comment: Aaahh of course! I did not recognize Riemann-Lebesgue in complex notation! Thanks!

Comment: Why do you even mention the integer values $n$?

Comment: @zhw I was thinking about Fourier series when I wrote it. You are right that I don't need to think about $n$.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to evaluate that integral outright, since it doesn't converge.  That being said, here's a reasonable approach: it is known that for any functions $f$ and $g$, we have
$$
\widehat{fg}(x) = (\hat f*\hat g)(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat f(y)\hat g(x-y)\,dy
$$
Thus, if this property is to be maintained, our $\hat f$ should be such that for any $g$:
$$
\hat g(x) = \widehat{fg}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat f(y)\hat g(x-y)\,dy
$$
that is, $\hat f$ must have the [sifting property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Translation).  In fact, this tells us that $\hat f$ must be the [dirac delta "function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) (which is, strictly speaking, not a function).